# Wix bootstrapper Launch target not working.

Tags: wix, target, launch, bootstrapper

I have a wix bootstrapper which, upon installation, launches the program it installs if the user clicks the "Launch" button. For some reason though, it does not launch the exe that it is supposed to, even though I see the following for LaunchTarget in my log file:

[1A8C:1184][2014-07-11T12:39:41]i410: Variable: LaunchTarget = C:\PD6\EXE\CW6.exe

Which is the exact location where I would find the file it should be launching.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it this [bug](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4470/)?  (It would only be in WiX 3.9.702).

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: It was indeed that bug Sean, thank you once again!